# Excel Formula - Match

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, mysql, microsoft-access

Can someone recommend a way to write a formula that will achieve the following. I can achieve these things individually but stringing together seems to be difficult.

I have a list of orders with various items in different fields and I need to check for valid entries based on criteria in another table. I want to match based on a 1 particular field that can be considered the work type unique identifier. Once the unique identifier is found I want to match the next few fields and return error message if match fails.

So something like (pseudo code)

```
"IF MATCH, THEN MATCH ADJACENT CELL, AND ADJACENT CELL, AND ADJACENT CELL, AND ADJACENT CELL".
```

Preferably the return displays states which column did not match, but if not possible then simply that the string has failed.

Don't mind if using lookup or index formula, or ms access.

Thanks Dave. I've added some visual representation of what I'm looking at.

Table showing orders, this table will change and is what needs to be checked for correct entries

[image]

Table showing the table used to cross-check order data in table 1

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you've tried first. It's easier for us to correct it. [Edit your question to show your formula](http://superuser.com/posts/942776/edit), you'll get a better response :)

Answer (score 1):

select * from table1 where table1.worktype_unique = table2.worktype_unique
AND table1.quanity<=table2.quantity_max AND table1.price <= table2.max_price;

add as many and conditions as you want.

This will detect non matching values only for manual fixing.
select * from table1 where table1.worktype_unique <> table2.worktype_unique;

Produces a set of orders where there is a problem.
select * from table1 where table1.worktype_unique = table2.worktype_unique
AND table1.quanity>table2.quantity_max OR table1.price > table2.max_price;